# Erlang crash without erl_crash.dump

Tags: linux, erlang, core-file

My server crashed down today. But Erlang did not generate erl_crash.dump.

ENV:

```
Linux 2.6.32

Erlang R16B02
```

I get from /var/log/message
[image]

CPU and Mem are normal at that time around(use sar)
[image]

Because the core file is too big
[image]

I just gdb corefile and bt full
[image]

If you want other more information from this core file or whatever others to help me, please leave comment.

I will post what you want soon.

Comment: If you get a segfault, that means the VM took a fatal error and so can't possibly continue operating in order to produce a crash dump. I suggest sending your information to the [erlang-bugs mailing list](http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs), but note that given that you're running on an older version of Erlang, there's a good chance this has already been fixed if it's really a VM bug.

Comment: Do you use any NIFs? It's more probable one of them crashes then Erlang VM itself